# c++ 2 dimension array rotation

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program in C++ to display a 2 dimensional array and then rotate it 90, 180, and 270 degrees. The array is a capital 'E' made of E's and blanks. I have written the program but when I run it it does print the E's rotated but vertically (top to bottom), my professor wants them rotated but to print horizontally (left to right).

By my logic I would have to edit my code to do:

-> print array row 1
-> rotate90
-> print array row 1
-> rotate90 (to revert to original)
-> rotate180
-> print array row 1
-> rotate180 (original)
-> rotate270
-> print array row 1
-> rotate 270 (original) ->

...continue 7 times until all rows are printed.

I know there is an easier way but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char eArray[][7]{
    {'E','E','E','E','E','E','E'},
    {'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'E','E','E','E','E',' ',' '},
    {'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {'E','E','E','E','E','E','E'},
};
int n = 7;

void rotateArray90(char a[][7]){

for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < n; j += 1) {
    swap(eArray[i][j], eArray[j][i]);
}}}

void flipArray180(char a[][7]){

for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j += 1) {
    swap(eArray[i][j], eArray[i][n-1-j]);
}}}

void rotateArray270(char a[][7]){

for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n/2; j += 1) {
    swap(eArray[i][j], eArray[n-1-i][j]);
}}}

void printArray(char a[][7]){

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
        cout << eArray[i][j] <<" ";
  }cout << endl;
}}

int main(){

printArray(eArray);
cout <<"\n";

rotateArray90(eArray);
printArray(eArray);
cout <<"\n";
rotateArray90(eArray);

flipArray180(eArray);
printArray(eArray);
cout <<"\n";
flipArray180(eArray);

rotateArray270(eArray);
printArray(eArray);
cout <<"\n";
rotateArray270(eArray);

}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: 4 copies of a 7x7 matrix isn't going to break the memory bank unless you're in the direst of extreme embedded systems.  Make four copies, rotated 0º, 90º, 180º, 270º (you only need a 'rotate 90º function — you copy the original and rotate the copy by 90º; you copy the 90º-rotated matrix and rotate the copy by 90º (for 180º rotation); you copy the 180º-rotated matrix and rotate the copy by 90º (for 270º rotation).  Now you arrange to print the lines of each of the 4 rotations across the page.

Comment: Even if you're not allowed to make copies, you still only need the rotate 90º function.  You print the first line of the unrotated matrix; then rotate 90º and print the first line of that; then rotate 90º more and print the first line of the now 180º rotated matrix; then you rotate 90º more and print the first line of the now 270º rotated matrix; then you rotate 90º more (to get back to the original) and move on printing the second row of the matrix after doing the rotation.

Comment: With C++'s standard IO stream once you issue a newline, there's no 100% reliable way to go back. You can allocate a buffer that's 4 E's wide and copy the rotated Es into it as you generate them, spaced a bit apart for easier reading, and then print the big buffer to the screen.

Comment: You might note that to revert to the original after a 90º rotation, you need to do a 270º rotation (or a -90º rotation), and not another 90º rotation, and conversely for the 270º rotation.  Two 180º rotations do get you back to where you started, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got you, but what you doing here is not a rotation (in the sense of matrix rotations). When you apply `rotateArray90(eArray)` two times you should get your array rotated 180 degrees, but instead it turns back to original array.
Here is my rotation method, take a look whether it helps. When you use it, you do not need separate methods for rotating at 180, 270 etc degrees, you just applies it 2, 3, ... times. After 4th rotation array returns back to original. It works with any rectangle array, not only `n x n`. And you do not have to use raw pointers, use instead containers.

```
template<typename T>
void printArray(const vector<vector<T>> &vch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vch.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vch[0].size(); ++j) {
            cout << vch[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void rotateArray(vector<vector<T>> &v)
{
    vector<vector<T>>rotated;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v[0].size(); i++) {
        vector<T> newRow;
        for (int j = v.size() - 1; j >=0; j--) {
            newRow.push_back(v[j][i]);
        }
        rotated.push_back(newRow);
    }
    v = rotated;
}
```

Here is an example how to use:

```
int main() {
    vector<vector<char>> vch = {
        {'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E'},
        { 'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
        { 'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
        { 'E','E','E','E','E',' ',' ' },
        { 'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
        { 'E',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
        { 'E','E','E','E','E','E','E' },
    };


    printArray<char>(vch);
    cout << "\n";
    rotateArray<char>(vch);
    printArray<char>(vch);
    cout << "\n";
    rotateArray<char>(vch);
    printArray<char>(vch);
    cout << "\n";
    rotateArray<char>(vch);
    printArray<char>(vch);
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}

//orignal
    E E E E E E E
    E
    E
    E E E E E
    E
    E
    E E E E E E E
 // rotated 90
    E E E E E E E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E           E
    E           E
 // rotated 180    
    E E E E E E E
                E
                E
        E E E E E
                E
                E
    E E E E E E E
 // rotated 270    
    E           E
    E           E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E     E     E
    E E E E E E E
    // rotated 360
    E E E E E E E
    E
    E
    E E E E E
    E
    E
    E E E E E E E
```